# Queuing jobs with async await in Node

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have the below code. I attempting to `console.log` the next `story` only after the previous `story` has been printed, but it is printing `Promise { <pending> }` . I am new to the `async` and `await`. What am I missing here?

Server

```
const express = require('express')
const async = require("async");
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const time = require('./timeoutFun.js')

const array = [
    {author: 'Bill',
    story: ['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'story']},
    {author: 'Frank',
    story: ['Here', 'goes', 'another']},
    {author: 'Tom',
    story: ['Fine', 'another', 'things', 'I', 'wrote']},
    {author: 'Sam',
    story: ['No', 'more', 'writings', 'please']}
]

array.forEach(element => {
    console.log(time.promiseTime(element))
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

timeoutFun.js

```
const time = {
    promiseTime: async function (obj) {
        const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
        return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(obj.story.toString() + " " + randomNum);
            }, randomNum * 1000);
        })
    }
}

module.exports = time;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't use `async function` and `return promise` together.. async functions return a promise automatically just return the end value, but in this case since you're using setTimeout then you'd need to return a promise so just use return promise.
2. forEach doesn't wait for promises to complete, so it starts them all and then skips to the next line, so use `for(let e of a){}` instead
3. You must `await` the promise such as `let result = await time.promiseTime(ele)` to actually get the value, otherwise you'll just get the promise (alternatively use `.then(result=>{...})`)

```js
const time = {
    promiseTime: function (obj) {
        const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(obj.story.toString() + " " + randomNum);
            }, randomNum * 1000);
        })
    }
};


const array = [
    {author: 'Bill',
    story: ['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'story']},
    {author: 'Frank',
    story: ['Here', 'goes', 'another']},
    {author: 'Tom',
    story: ['Fine', 'another', 'things', 'I', 'wrote']},
    {author: 'Sam',
    story: ['No', 'more', 'writings', 'please']}
];

async function main(){
  for(let ele of array){
      let result = await time.promiseTime(ele);
      console.log(result);
  };
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the great explanation